# Add column to DataFrame in a loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a very simple pandas dataframe, containing a single indexed column with "initial values". I want to read in a loop N other dataframes to fill a single "comparison" column, with matching indices.

For instance, with my inital dataframe as

```
   Initial
0        a
1        b
2        c
3        d
```

and the following two dataframes to read in a loop

```
   Comparison
0           e
1           f
   Comparison
2           g
3           h
4           i  <= note that this index doesn't exist in Initial so won't be matched
```

I would like to produce the following result

```
    Initial Comparison
0        a           e
1        b           f
2        c           g
3        d           h
```

Using `merge`, `concat` or `join`, I only ever seem to be able to create a new column for each iteration of the loop, filling the blanks with `NaN`.

What's the most pandas-pythonic way of achieving this?

---

Below an example from the proposed duplicate solution:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]), columns=['Initial'])
print df1
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['e'],['f']]), columns=['Compare'])
print df2
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[2,'g'],[3,'h'],[4,'i']]), columns=['','Compare'])
df3 = df3.set_index('')
print df3
print df1.merge(df2,left_index=True,right_index=True).merge(df3,left_index=True,right_index=True)
>>
      Initial
0       a
1       b
2       c
3       d
  Compare
0       e
1       f
  Compare

2       g
3       h
4       i
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Initial, Compare_x, Compare_y]
Index: []
```

---

**Second edit:** @W-B, the following seems to work, but it can't be the case that there isn't a simpler option using proper pandas methods. It also requires turning off warnings, which might be dangerous...

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
df1["Compare"]=pd.Series()
for ind in df1.index.values:
    if ind in df2.index.values:
        df1["Compare"][ind]=df2.T[ind]["Compare"]
    if ind in df3.index.values:
        df1["Compare"][ind]=df3.T[ind]["Compare"]
print df1
>>
      Initial Compare
0           a       e
1           b       f
2           c       g
3           d       h
```

Comment: This is reduce merge problem

Comment: Thanks for the link @W-B, but I don't think it's the same problem... The reduce+merge solution outlined there is to add several columns to a dataframe. Here, I want to merge several columns in one, based on the indexing.

Comment: left_index right_index , or just change merge to join

Comment: @W-B Sorry, but I still don't see what you mean (I've edited the post). I'm very new to this, so there's probably something obvious I'm missing...

Comment: @W-B further edit, found a working solution, but it's really ugly and inefficient... suggestions?

Comment: Would you like me reopen the question and provide the solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , since Op need more info

---

Data input

```
import functools
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]), columns=['Initial'])
df1['Compare']=np.nan
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['e'],['f']]), columns=['Compare'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.array(['g','h','i']), columns=['Compare'],index=[2,3,4])
```

---

Solution

```
newdf=functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x.fillna(y),[df1,df2,df3])
newdf
Out[639]: 
  Initial Compare
0       a       e
1       b       f
2       c       g
3       d       h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That _is_ a much nicer way :)